# Chromium magnet link not opening in qbittorrent

Tags: chromium, qbittorrent

New to linux, just installed Ubuntu. When I click on a magnet link, I get a prompt asking if I want to open "xdg-open". I accept and then nothing happens. I entered the following based on something I found online (don't know what these commands do) and found the following:

```
john@john-MacBookPro:~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
john@john-MacBookPro:~$ gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet
Default application for “x-scheme-handler/magnet”: org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
Registered applications:
    org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
Recommended applications:
    org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
```

If I download the .torrent and click on it, qbittorrent opens up and works fine.

Sorry, forgot to mention, this is Ubuntu 19.10 on a 2017 Macbook Pro laptop.

Comment: Not sure but might be a chromium snap problem.  Snaps have very few permissions, can try going to software centre/store and see if you can give more permissions, should just be on/off switch, or might need to use another browser(deb not snap).  Chromium might have a deb only version now again, but not sure if for 19.10 or only 20.04.

Comment: Looks like its a bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1853008

Comment: Here is a link to install a deb version of chromium,  seems like it be easier to use another browser myself.  https://shevchuk.co/notes/2019/12/13/install-chromium-on-ubuntu-1910-from-debian-instead-of-snap

Comment: Thanks. I'm a recent Linux immigrant and I use Google infrastructure, syncing with Chrome, everywhere else (home, office, etc). That's why I want to stick with Chrome(ium) on this laptop where I'm trialing Linux.

Comment: Chrome works well with Linux, so chromium not your only choice.

Comment: Oh, great, thanks, I didn't know that. I'm a new so only looking at the built in Ubuntu software application. I'm learning more terminal commands so I'll figure out how to install Chrome.